# URL on List button not accessible through LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, custom-button, pagereference

I need to override the 'New' button for a custom object on related list present on Opportunity.
I'm navigating to a custom app page in which I have my LWC component. I need to pass the Opportunity name to my LWC component. Below is the URL I have added in the button.

```
{!URLFOR( '/lightning/n/myCustomAppPage?c__oppName=' + URLENCODE( Opportunity.Name ))}
```

Below is the LWC code:

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { CloseActionScreenEvent } from 'lightning/actions';
import { CurrentPageReference } from 'lightning/navigation';
export default class MyCustomCmp extends  LightningElement{
    @api recordId;
    oppName = null;
    @wire(CurrentPageReference)
    getStateParameters(currentPageReference) {
        if (currentPageReference) {
            this.oppName = currentPageReference.state?.c__oppName;
            console.log("currentPageReference"+JSON.stringify(currentPageReference));
            console.log("currentPageReference.state"+JSON.stringify(currentPageReference.state));
        }
    }
```

Below is the log I'm getting for `currentPageReference.state`

```
{"c__recordId":"","ws":"/lightning/r/My_Custom_Object__c/a1o530000009ln7AAA/view"}
```

The `oppName` parameter is not getting passed to LWC. What should I change?

Comment: How your link looks like?

Comment: Its a normal custom button on related list which says 'New custom object'. This redirects to my custom app page. This page has my LWC component.

Comment: Yeah, could you show me the URL when you are redirected to the custom app page?

Comment: https://dev.sandbox.lightning.force.com/lightning/n/myCustomAppPage?c__recordId=&ws=%2Flightning%2Fr%2FMy_Custom_Object__c%2Fa1o530000009ln7AAA%2Fview

Comment: You don't have `c__oppName` in this URL so this is why you don't see `c__oppName` in `currentPageReference.state`